# Custom query in spring boot JPA using postgres db

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am connecting my spring boot application to postgres db, i am able insert values using JPA. Now i want to retrieve data from the table. I would like to use the @Query from JPA to select the column in the table. while i run the application i get sql error. Here is the repository code

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user.firstname AS firstName, user.lastName AS lastName FROM user_details user WHERE emailid LIKE ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    EmailOnly findUserByEmail(String emailId);

       public static interface EmailOnly {

         String getFirstName();

         String getLastName();
      }
```

Entity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int userId;
    private String emailId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

I get error as

> SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601 2020-03-23 17:04:05.128 ERROR 27508 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR:
>   syntax error at or near **"."**

All the example in jpa shows to select data using aliases, but its now working for me. ***If i try to remove all the aliases from the query i am getting the projection values as null.***

Comment: Please show your entity and table column names

Comment: running the query in PGADMIn also gives sysntax error at ".", but how should i make the query to get the values from DB?

Comment: If i remove the aliases in PGADMIN query works, but the same query in JPA gives back an object but the projection does not have any values, i.e its null. In this case getFirstName and getLastName

Comment: Why do you need native query?

Comment: I am just learning how to do this, in complex join scenarios, i could use them right?